# How to add custom div in wordpress static page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Here I have a Wordpress theme, which is working fine.

Now I want to append my custom div under existing content. here are 2 existing panels which are following:

[image]

I'm new comer in WordPress so kindly assist me, how to achieve this requirement. your kind efforts would be heartily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: **Open your wp-content->themes->your Theme Name-> footer.php**
at very top beginning add div there but make sure it will show on all page.
Example:

```
<div class="infooterfile"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <div class="icoach-section">
            <div class="footer-logo fadeIn animated">
                <?php
                    $icoach_dark_logo=get_theme_mod('icoach_dark_logo');
                    $icoach_dark_logo=wp_get_attachment_url($icoach_dark_logo);
                ?>
                <?php if($icoach_dark_logo != '' && !empty($icoach_dark_logo)): ?>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo esc_url($icoach_dark_logo); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e('Logo','icoach');?>">
                <?php endif; ?>      
            </div>
```

**NOTE:** If you want to show it only home page then you need to add div above `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in home page separate template.

EXAMPLE: in homepage separate template

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 **/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="heading-wrap blog-heading-wrap" >
    <div class="heading-layer">
        <div class="heading-title">
            <h1><?php _e('Blog ','icoach'); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="yourdiv"></div>
<?php get_template_part('content'); get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks brother for your kind response, can you tell me where our static page file exist in our theme directory ?

Comment: are you using any page builder like visual composer?

Comment: if you want to add div on your static page then you need to edit your homepage from admin end but make sure it will not come with full width.